# Question about the boundedness of a bilinear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a question regarding the boundedness of a bilinear operator in the context of functional analysis. Let's consider the following setting:

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq1$. We have a bilinear operator $B: L^2(\Omega) \times L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ defined as $B(y_1, y_2) = y_1 \times y_2$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are functions in $L^2(\Omega)$.

In $L^2(\Omega)$, the norm is given by $$|y| = \left(\int_{\Omega}y^2(x) \ \mathrm  dx\right)^{1/2}.$$

**My question is:** Is the operator $B$ a bounded operator?

I initially thought this question would have a straightforward answer, but I feel like I might be overlooking something. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let $\Omega=(0,1)$, note that $x\mapsto x^{-\frac14}$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$. But the square of this map is not in $L^2$ (rather it is in $L^1$). So your map is not well defined.

Comment: I see. even the operator's well-posedness fails. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is currently ill-defined. Consider the following $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-1/4} & \text{ for } x \in (0,1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Now notice however that $f \cdot f \not\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$!

EDIT: only after posting this answer I saw @s.harp's identical comment.